# Matlab weka Interface

Tags: matlab, weka

I'm using the [Matlab Weka Interface](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21204-matlab-weka-interface). When I want to convert MALTAB data to [WEKA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_%28machine_learning%29) data by `matlab2weka`, I get the following error:

??? Java exception occurred:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be
cast to java.lang.String

```
at weka.core.Attribute.<init>(Attribute.java:344)

at weka.core.Attribute.<init>(Attribute.java:299)
```

Error in ==> matlab2weka at 38
                vec.addElement(Attribute(featureNames{i},values));

My data is nominal, but for numeric there is no problem!

Comment: do you have a non-standard character in any of the strings, possibly a quotation mark or a single (') mark. Or possible something that may be interpretted as an escape character the conversion may not like. (Ex. `\n` or `\r`)

Comment: no. I found that another person have a problem like me in Mathworks.com! I will put it here: 
I have no problem saving an nxd array of numbers. However, when I then create an nxd cell with one column being filled with 'fail' and 'pass' I get the following error when executing matlab2weka:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to
java.lang.String
at weka.core.Attribute.<init>(Attribute.java:341)
at weka.core.Attribute.<init>(Attribute.java:300)
Error in ==> matlab2weka at 37
vec.addElement(Attribute(featureNames{i},values));

Comment: this is likely because you are using numbers and words.That may just be an issue. Try representing pass and fail with numbers, like 1 and 0 respectively

Comment: I understand why this error appear. when I want to send a single character such as f/m for attribute sex this errors caused. but for more than 1 character such as male or no there is no problem!

Comment: but the problem still remained!!!

Comment: @parmin did you find a solution. I am facing the exact same problem in a worser form. I want to run my code on a cluster. It works fine on all my windows computers and it also works on some nodes on the cluster (which run linux). But when i deploy it on the cluster at large, it fails with the problem you mention. Wierd !!!

Comment: Also my error is slightly different -- i get weka.core.Attribute cannot be cast to weka.core.Attribute in weka.core.Instances<init>